# Android Checkbox in Custom Preference not updating

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-widget, android-preferences

I'm attempting to implement a custom `CheckBoxPreference` - one where, if a user clicks on the actual checkbox it toggles the state, but if they click on the name it opens a preference fragment instead. To do so I've overridden the `OnBindView(View view)` method, removed the `view`'s Click listener, and am attempting to add an `OnClickListener` to each of its child views individually. However, the `OnClickListener` bound to the `Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatCheckBox` does not update the checkbox's visible state, even though the preference itself has succesfully been saved

```
protected override void OnBindView(View view)
{       
    base.OnBindView(view);
    view.Clickable = false;
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)view;
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.ChildCount - 1; i++)
    {
        vg.GetChildAt(i).SetOnClickListener(new DoOpenFragment(this));
    }
    vg.GetChildAt(vg.ChildCount - 1).SetOnClickListener(new DoCheckBoxClick(this)); 
}

private class DoCheckBoxClick : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
{
    private OpenFragmentCheckboxPreference Pref;
    public DoCheckBoxClick(OpenFragmentCheckboxPreference pref)
    {
        Pref = pref;
    }
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        var b0 = Pref.GetPersistedBoolean(true);
        Pref.PersistBoolean(!b0);
        var cb = ((v as ViewGroup).GetChildAt(0) as Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatCheckBox);
        var b1 = Pref.GetPersistedBoolean(true);
        cb.Checked = b1;
        Pref.NotifyChanged();
        cb.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I try to use both the Preference's `NotifyChanged` method and the actual CheckBox widget's `Invalidate` method, but neither works. (The extra, unnecessary variables are just for debugging). Any idea what call I might be missing that would actually cause the checkbox to be redrawn and display its correct state? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I should have been setting `CheckBox.Checked` in `OnBindView`, NOT in the `OnClick` Listener:

```
    protected override void OnBindView(View view)
    {
        base.OnBindView(view);
        view.Clickable = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.ChildCount - 1; i++)
        {
            vg.GetChildAt(i).SetOnClickListener(new DoOpenFragment(this));
        }
        ((vg.GetChildAt(vg.ChildCount - 1) as ViewGroup).GetChildAt(0) as Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatCheckBox).Checked = GetPersistedBoolean(true);
        vg.GetChildAt(vg.ChildCount - 1).SetOnClickListener(new DoCheckBoxClick(this));
    }

    private class DoCheckBoxClick : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        private OpenFragmentCheckboxPreference Pref;
        public DoCheckBoxClick(OpenFragmentCheckboxPreference pref)
        {
            Pref = pref;
        }
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            var b0 = Pref.GetPersistedBoolean(true);
            Pref.PersistBoolean(!b0);
            Pref.NotifyChanged();
        }
    }
```